# How to exclude a specific folder in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When user hits

- http://localhost/mywebsite/folder1

this link my htaccess is working.

But when user hits

- http://localhost/mywebsite/folder2

my website redirect to

- http://localhost/folder2

because my website contains folder2 in my directory structure.

When user hits

- http://localhost/mywebsite/folder2

my htaccess should ignore this URL because I want to redirect user to index.php which present in folder2

The code written below is present in my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What should I do?
Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Where is this htaccess located?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to exclude the folder 'exclude_me' . 
Adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exclude_me/.*$
```

does the trick for me

Comment: It's redirect to localhost/exclude_me when I hits localhost/mywebsite/exclude_me

Comment: and says object not fould

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/excluded-folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]